# Retrieve commandLine value from a Window Service

Tags: windows, service, command-line

I am looking for a way, if any exists, to view the value of *CommandLine* argument with which a Windows service was created. Although, this is possible for viewing from Windows Registry, recommending users to open-up registry every time for this purpose concerns me from a safety view-point.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE: I was trying to get the CMD line values to get hold of the JVM options set with the process. This is possible using Process Explorer [from Windows]. Just choose the process in question, hit properties, navigate to Environment tab and you can see all JVM options set for your process here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows Vista and Windows 7 it is possible to view the command-line of any process, including services, via the Task Manager. To view the command-line goto `View->Select Columns...` and tick the `Command Line` box.

Another option is to view the Service in the Services Applet. To start `Start->Run` and enter `services.msc`. You can then browse to the desired service, double-click it and view the `Path to executable` field.

Comment: Path to Executable field do not seem to contain CommandLine argument fully. But, your first suggestion serves the purpose. :-)

Comment: @Srii, If you click on the `Path to executable` field you can then move the cursor along.

Comment: Your second suggestion did not work in Windows 7/ Windows Server 2008.

Comment: @Srii, I am on Windows 7 and it works fine. Anyhow, glad you got a solution.